# Torsion-free Cohen-Macaulay modules

Tags: commutative-algebra, formal-power-series, cohen-macaulay

We say an $R$-module $M$ over integral domain $R$ is a torsion-free module if zero is the only element annihilated by some non-zero element of the ring $R$. Let $R=K[[x_1,\dots ,x_d]]$, $d>1$, be the formal power series ring over a field $K$. It is clear that $R$ is a Cohen-Macaulay ring of dimension $d$.

> Is there any Cohen-Macaulay $R$-module $M$ of dimension $d-1$ such that $M$ is also torsion-free as an $R$-module?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For every finitely generated module $\dim M=\dim R/\mathrm{Ann}_R(M)$. Since $M$ is torsion-free, $\mathrm{Ann}_R(M)=(0)$, hence $\dim M=\dim R$.

In particular, a CM torsion-free module is MCM.

Comment: This cannot hold in general, right? That $\operatorname{Ann}_R(M) = (0)$ follows from the hypothesis that $R$ is a domain. Otherwise, the assumption that $M$ is torsion-free only says that no $R$-regular element annihilates $M.$

Comment: In general, torsion-free does not imply faithful.